# promise chaining after auto-resolve

Tags: node.js, promise

When it comes to nodejs promises: which implementation of chaining is a better practice and why?

```
Promise.resolve()
      .then(() => somePromise())
      .then(() => anotherPromise())
      .catch(e => log(e));
```

versus

```
somePromise()
      .then(() => anotherPromise())
      .catch(e => log(e));
```

Comment: The latter is better. The former creates an additional Promise for no reason.

Comment: Also, if the callback to then takes no argument, or just passes the argument on: `.then(anotherPromise)`

Comment: @Paulpro does it make a difference for catching errors inside the chained promises?

Comment: @jfabfab No, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Paulpro - That's not entirely true.  There is a difference in error handling if `somePromise()` could ever throw synchronously or not return a promise.  See my  answer below for details.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yeah, I assumed that `somePromise` is a function that always returns a Promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as `somePromise()` always returns a promise and doesn't throw synchronously, there's no reason to start the chain with `Promise.resolve()`.  That just creates extra code to run that is not necessary.  You can just start the chain with `somePromise()` instead (as in your 2nd example).

But, if `somePromise()` could throw synchronously and you wanted that to be routed into your `.catch()` handler, then your first option is one way to do that.  I would argue that `somePromise()` is poorly designed if it could both return a promise and throw synchronously, but if that turned out to be the case and it wasn't your code that you could fix, then your first option would be one way to work around that bad design.

---

Also, if your functions really take no custom arguments (though I realize this may just be pseudocode), you don't need the extra functions.  You can do:

```
somePromise()
    .then(anotherPromise)
    .catch(log);
```

---

Another possibility is to use the ability to catch both synchronous exceptions and promise errors and deal with functions that occasionally don't return a promise with `await` and `try/catch`.

```
async function myFunc() {
    try {
        await somePromise();
        await anotherPromise();
    } catch(e) {
        log(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jfriend00 is right and nailed it with synchronous errors, but I would warmly recommend you consider `async`/`await` over chaining which is preferred. There are numerous benefit (performance, better stack traces and easier code):

try {
    await somePromise();
    await anotherPromise());
  } catch (e) { log(e); }

Mostly, in new Node if somePromise throws inside - you will get a stack frame (in production) showing the calling code whereas with regular chaining you would not.